# PayPal button is not displayed in Laravel using client side REST api

Tags: javascript, laravel, paypal

I have added PayPal payment option to my website. I have integrated the code for PayPal payment as below:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
 <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
                        <div class="sec_pay_hd">
                            Payment Method
                        </div>
                        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
                        <div id="confirm" class="hidden">
                                    <div>Ship to:</div>
                                    <div><span id="recipient"></span>, <span id="line1"></span>, <span id="city"></span></div>
                                    <div><span id="state"></span>, <span id="zip"></span>, <span id="country"></span></div>

                                    <button id="confirmButton">Complete Payment</button>
                                </div>
                                <div id="thanks" class="hidden">
                                            Thanks, <span id="thanksname"></span>!
                                        </div>
                        <!-- <div class="pay_mode_img1 visa_imgsasa"> -->
                        <!-- </div> -->
                        <script>
                                    paypal.Button.render({

                                        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

                                        client: {
                                            sandbox:    'AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R',
                                            production: '<insert production client id>'
                                        },

                                        payment: function(data, actions) {
                                            return actions.payment.create({
                                                payment: {
                                                    transactions: [
                                                        {
                                                            amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' }
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            });
                                        },

                                        // Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer

                                        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

                                            // Get the payment details

                                            return actions.payment.get().then(function(data) {

                                                // Display the payment details and a confirmation button

                                                var shipping = data.payer.payer_info.shipping_address;

                                                document.querySelector('#recipient').innerText = shipping.recipient_name;
                                                document.querySelector('#line1').innerText     = shipping.line1;
                                                document.querySelector('#city').innerText      = shipping.city;
                                                document.querySelector('#state').innerText     = shipping.state;
                                                document.querySelector('#zip').innerText       = shipping.postal_code;
                                                document.querySelector('#country').innerText   = shipping.country_code;

                                                document.querySelector('#paypal-button-container').style.display = 'none';
                                                document.querySelector('#confirm').style.display = 'block';

                                                // Listen for click on confirm button

                                                document.querySelector('#confirmButton').addEventListener('click', function() {

                                                    // Disable the button and show a loading message

                                                    document.querySelector('#confirm').innerText = 'Loading...';
                                                    document.querySelector('#confirm').disabled = true;

                                                    // Execute the payment

                                                    return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {

                                                        // Show a thank-you note

                                                        document.querySelector('#thanksname').innerText = shipping.recipient_name;

                                                        document.querySelector('#confirm').style.display = 'none';
                                                        document.querySelector('#thanks').style.display = 'block';
                                                    });
                                                });
                                            });
                                        }

                                    }, '#paypal-button-container');

                                </script>

                        <div class="visa_imgsasa">
                            <img src="{{asset('assets/resources/images/visa-image.png')}}" alt="">
                        </div>
```

I have added paypal script on the top of the page. But now i am getting this error repeatedly

[image: screenshot for error part-1]

[image]

any sort of help is appreciated, I have searched for this error on web but couldn't find any. This is the sample code from the demo of paypal website.But this is also not working on my local server.

Comment: I'd be glad to help debug (I maintain checkout.js) -- is there a live page where I can repro this error?

Comment: removed comment containing link to site. _/\_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('nav#menu').mmenu();`

^ Removing this from your page fixes the problem. My guess is removes the iframe from the DOM and then re-adds it, which causes the iframe's internal window to close.

Comment: thank you very much, now its working smoothly. mmenu is a third party script to manage mobile menu, to slide right. Somehow this is interfering with the paypal code, I am working on to resolve that. But this is such a relief. Thank you so very much !!